# Android Error: No resource found that matches the given name in Android Studio

Tags: android

I downloaded a template web wrapper template Web2App to wrap my website in an android app.

I want to run the app in the emulator but keep getting errors. 
I was originally getting a AndroidManifest.xml file missing error, but then i went into project manager -> Facets and changed the route to where my manifest file was. Not sure if that has something to do with the current errors. But if i change it back, then ill get the missing android manifest.xml

I keep getting these errors when trying to run my app on the emulator:

```
Error:(27, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [Template] /Users/gqwebsites/Downloads/Template/template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:27: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').

Error:(19, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [Template] /Users/gqwebsites/Downloads/Template/template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').

Error:(19, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [Template] /Users/gqwebsites/Downloads/Template/template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.Toolbar').

 Error:(25, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [Template]   /Users/gqwebsites/Downloads/Template/template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:25:   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

heres whats in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    android:name="com.sherdle.webtoapp.App">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sherdle.webtoapp.activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mysite.com" ></data>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*.mysite.com" ></data>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mysite.com" ></data>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.mysite.com" ></data>
        </intent-filter>-->
    </activity>

    <!-- ADS -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    <!-- Analytics-->
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

</application>
```

my strings.xml looks like :

```
<resources>
<!--Configure your App's name, as displayed in the launcher and optionally the Toolbar -->
<string name="app_name">PlugMatch</string>
<!--Configure your Admob ID below, or leave empty if you do not want to enable Ads in your app -->
<string name="ad_banner_id"></string>
<string name="ad_interstitial_id"></string>


<string name="previous">Previous</string>
<string name="next">Next</string>
<string name="stop">Stop</string>
<string name="no_connection">No internet connection was found</string>
<string name="ok">Ok</string>
<string name="yes">Yes</string>
<string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="share">Share</string>
<string name="error">Error</string>
<string name="about">About</string>
<string name="home">Home</string>
<string name="close">Close</string>
<string name="download">Download</string>
<string name="saved">Saved at: </string>
<string name="sharetitle">Share this!</string>
<string name="notification_settings">Notification settings</string>
<string name="download_fail">Download failed</string>
<string name="download_done">The file has been saved in the downloads folder, open it by tapping the file in your notifications</string>
<string name="exit_message">Thank you for using our app!</string>
<string name="no_app_message">No app found to complete this action!</string>
<string name="dialog_about"><![CDATA[The Social Network for Music Professionals.]]></string>
<string name="drawer_open">Open drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close drawer</string>

<string name="download_permission_explaination">In order to download files, you need to grant us permission to your storage.\n\nAfter granting us access, you may go ahead and download the file.</string>

<string name="common_permission_explaination">In order to use this app, you need to grant us some permissions.</string>
<string name="common_permission_grant">Grant permission</string>

<string name="share1">I came across </string>
<!--  we will automatically website title here-->
<string name="share2"> using </string>
<!--  we will automatically put your apps name and link here -->

<string name="rate_later">Perhaps later</string>
<string name="rate_never">No thanks</string>
<string name="rate_yes">Yes</string>
<string name="rate_message">We hope you enjoy using %1$s. Would you like to help us by rating us in the Store?</string>
<string name="rate_title">Enjoying our app?</string>
```

Comment: You are missing value folder in res directory.  Just take the suggestion from IDE and create thoose!

Comment: can you post strings.xml?

Comment: @sasikumar I updated question with the strings.xml , I already had this but still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Create values folder under res folder
Create values -> strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Web2App</string>
</resources>
```

Create values -> styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">           
    </style>
</resources>
```

Create values -> mipmap -> ic_launcher.png

In build.gradle Check

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Also AndroidManifest.xml should be under src -> main

Comment: Version 8.3.0? You should consider upgrading your code

Comment: Yup @cricket_007 I will be. Thanks

Comment: @AliSafdar I already have those values in my strings.xml I updated my post so you can see what i have. But still getting same errors

Comment: Can you try to remove android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" and then compile. To see if the actual errors are theses. Or somewhere else.

Comment: @AliSafdar i removed like you said then got this : Error:(21, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [Template] /Users/gqwebsites/Downloads/Template/template/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: @Luna Is this AndroidManifest.xml complete. Because manifest tag is missing. <manifest package="com.example.test"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> </manifest>. This should wrap around <application> tag